# Nav bar set to translucent black displaying white on simulator

Tags: swift3, uinavigationbar, xcode8

I'm looking to change the nav bar of my view controller to the translucent black setting using the simulated metrics. Unfortunately, when run, the simulator still appears white. I've looked through numerous SO questions regarding the various attempts - nav bar manipulation through simulated metrics, changing the status bar style via the app delegate and in my view controller and playing with the view controller-based status bar in the info.plist. Unsure how to approach my problem from here.

[image]

Comment: You want to change it through storyboard or code? And you want to apply this to one view controller or through out the app?

Comment: I was looking to change it through the storyboard, however, at this point, I'll happily take code. I'm aware of the difference between the individual controller and app delegate; simply looking for a solution at this point.

Comment: Now are you adding it through storyboard or code?

Comment: I initially attempted the storyboard - hence the included picture, and then code.

Answer (score 0):

Add the Navigation bar in Xcode :

Then you can change the navbar color using code like below:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.black
UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = true
```

If you want to apply it in storyboard, then

[image]